# How can I block apps and websites (e.g. youtube) at certain times (e.g. when I'm supposed to be working) in a way that I can't easily disable it?

Tags: linux, browser, website

I have a problem (like many others) of procrastination (well technically I'm procrastinating while writing this...) and I want to limit what I can do on the computer when I'm supposed to be doing something else. I want a way that I can block apps and websites in a way that I can't easily disable it, I've tried various options but most are too easy to change. It can't rely on a 3rd party (person) remembering a password or anything. Somehow, it has to not be able to be disabled just by `sudo killall appname` or similar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A router that allows you to fully configure the firewall (linux iptables) would enable you to configure rules to block the sites you want to lock yourself out of during specific times, and also prevent connections to the router's admin interface and ssh so you have to wait until after hours to connect and unblock yourself.

If the stock router firmware doesn't allow iptables rules, there may be an option to load it with OpenWRT, which certainly does.

This guide isn't exactly what you want, but it has most of the elements: http://whirlysworld.blogspot.com/2013/08/blocking-internet-at-specific-times.html

You should be able to sort out the rest of it using a few other iptables tricks like what is described here:
https://defragged.org/2020/03/14/blocking-http-requests-via-iptables-for-a-specific-domain/
and here:
https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-how-to-block-incoming-and-outgoing-ports-using-iptables/

Comment: BTW, I realize this only blocks access to network resources and doesn't address time-waster apps like games.  The original post hinted that it was a "computer" so maybe that implies mac or pc (the solutions would be different).  I'll also save someone the trouble of commenting that blocking yourself out of your own router admin is risky... so be very careful not to mess it up and block yourself out completely / forever.

Comment: I'm on Linux (hence the tag). Anyway thanks for the answer, I'll have a look into it

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this timed safe: [https://www.amazon.com/Kitchen-Safe-Locking-Container-Height/dp/B00E9J3MLM/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=ksafe&qid=1598274499&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E9J3MLM)
is the easiest way for me. I change my modem password, block sites and access times, and then lock it away.

perhaps make a work account on your computer and lock away your main account (the one with the games) password in the safe.

If you need a solution cheap/immediately, mail the passwords to yourself (2 letters just in case?).

If your phone is distracting you also, ios has a password lock feature for content restrictions that could utilise what im talking about. android devices I've used can't do this so you'd have to lock it in the safe instead of restricting distracting features.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could (carefully) try a tool called Lockout, which temporarily disables your sudo access, as well as anything else you want it to do. For more info see this article: https://www.linux.com/news/lock-productivity-lockout-utility/

*I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across it when trying to remember the name of this Lockout tool which I had used on a previous computer but then forgot the name of. If this doesn't help you, perhaps it will help others.*

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.